# Mysql, combine two sql query in one statement

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

***1) jb_theme_metadata***

**column : idx  | t_name**

1 | sports

2 | movies

***2) jb_theme***

**column : idx | theme_idx(F key of jb_theme_metadata) | u_idx (F key of jb_user)**

1 | 1 | 3

2 | 1 | 4

3 | 1 | 5

4 | 2 | 7

***expected output***

**column : idx | t_name | user_count**

1 | sports | 3

2 | moives | 1

Can I make this output by a sql query not two statements?

Comment: where is your queries?

Answer (score 0):

May be this would work for you:

```
SELECT m.idx, m.t_name, COUNT(t.u_idx) as user_count
FROM jb_theme_metadata AS m
JOIN jb_theme AS t ON t.theme_idx=m.idx
GROUP BY t.theme_idx
```